# .htaccess issue with redirecting not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My `.htaccess` file works fine but I want to make a change on the redirect.

Currently, it redirect the url to `http://www.mywebsite.com/tool/url/google.com`

Now... I want to remove the `url` path from it. So, I want `http://www.mywebsite.com/tool/google.com`

My code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(url)/(.*)$  /tool/script.php?url=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$  /tool/script.php?url=$2 [L,QSA]
```

And

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  /tool/script.php?url=$2 [L,QSA]
```

But all is giving me 404 error. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2 doesn't exist, it should be $1 to reference the first (and only, in your code) match.